# TLS connection with Thales Payshield 9000

Tags: security, connection, certificate, csr, hsm

I would like to set up a TLS connection between a host and an hsm thales payshield. On the HSM I have generated the RSA key pair but I can only get the csr.

> Can't I generate a self signed certificate? Are there alternative
> methods?

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you need to create your own ROOT CA, use it to sign the CRT of the payShield, then create a client certificate using your ROOT CA.
The certificates you generate need to be version v3!

Then you can finally upload them to your payShield using the payShield Manager or though USB stick (I tried on the 10k).

You need to upload to the payShield three certificates:
the CRT of your CA
the CRT of your payShield obtained signing the certificate request of it
the CRT of your client.

Kind regards,
Marco - StockTrader

Comment: Hi Marco, I solved with the HSM. Now I have problems with the pc to connect .. could you tell me in the java Keysore which files must be present? I get an error like: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Hello Melk. They payShield does not have a 'default' client so I think it depends on the application that you're using to connect the host port.
You can try to verify that your TLS setup is correct using a test tool such as **HSM COMMANDER** from **EFT LABS** or my simple tool that you can find here: [link](https://github.com/mszeu/PayShieldPPressureTest)